# FrameLayout doesn't fit the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-framelayout

so I'm developing an app that uses a FrameLayout as a fragment container, whose content depends on the selected item on the Bottom Navigator. My problem is, for some reason, I can't get the FrameLayout to fit the whole screen so I always have a blank space on top of the fragment whenever I run the app. I've tried to change the length, change margins but nothing seems to work. What am I missing? Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.038"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.094" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's the result:

[image: The blank space appears where the arrow is pointed to.]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your `ConstraintLayout` has a top padding, so the children will never be able to reach the top.

If you want full screen, remove this from the `ConstraintLayout`

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!